# Add multiple divs inside the td on keypress jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a input text box inside a `div` which is in a `td`, now when the user enters some text and press enter it should add an additional div with input box to the same td. The goal is to have multiple values in subsequent rows.

I'm able to add the div on keypress but the problem here is I'm not able to make the keypress fire only once. I have used flag to make it fire only once but it didn't work in my case.

Before the keypress event

```
<div id="grid">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="first-row">
<div><input class ="td-input"></input></div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

After adding the div on key press dom will be like below

```
<div id="grid">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="first-row">
<div><input class ="td-input"></input></div>
<div><input class="td-input"></input></div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

JQuery

```
$('#grid').on('keypress','td.first-row > div input.td-input', 
function(event){
var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
var currentTD,addDiv;
if(key == '13'){
currentTD = $(this).closest('td');
addDiv = '<div><input class="td-input"></input></div>';
currentTD.append(addDiv);
}
});
```

I want 'div' to be added only once for each keypress on the input text box.
With my code, 2 divs will be added if press enter twice.

Please refer the below image for output.

```js
$('#grid').on('keypress', 'td.first-row > div input.td-input', function(event){
    var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    var currentTD,addDiv;
    if(key == '13'){
     currentTD = $(this).closest('td');
     addDiv = '<div class="additional-row"><input class="td-input"></input></div>';
     currentTD.append(addDiv);
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div><input class ="td-input" placeholder="Enter here column 1"></input></div>
</td>
<td class="first-row">
<div><input class ="td-input" placeholder="Enter here column 2"></input></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That bottom snippet of jQuery code, how is that being executed to create the binding?

Comment: I'm using the above jQuery snippet in the document ready and I'm binding the keypress event to the input box so that when the user types and press enters. It triggers the event.

Comment: So you are only ever executing that `on()` statement once?

Comment: I just tried your runnable snippet.  Repeatedly hitting enter in the second box only inserts one new input each time.

Comment: Yes, what I want is no matter how many enters i press on the second input box it should only add one input box but now it adds input box for every key enter.

Comment: So you mean at most it should only add one.

Comment: Yes, restrict adding the new input when the user presses enter on the same input twice or more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only allow a single enter on an input to insert a new input, since you are already using a delegate, you can change it to test that the input does not have a class.  Once the event handler is processed for an input, by adding the class to it, you ensure that it will not be repeated for future enters.

```js
$('#grid').on('keypress', 'td.first-row > div input.td-input:not(.processed)', function(event) {
  var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

  if (key == 13) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $td = $this.closest('td');
    
    $td.append('<div class="additional-row"><input class="td-input"></input></div>');
    $this.addClass('processed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input class="td-input" placeholder="Enter here column 1"></input>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="first-row">
        <div><input class="td-input" placeholder="Enter here column 2"></input>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use a named event handler and then the [`.off()` JQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to de-register the previously registered handler just before it completes.

Also, `keypress` is the wrong event for testing the ENTER key (is doesn't fire for non-printable characters). For that, use `keydown`.

Lastly, the `input` element doesn't have a closing tag (`</input>`). That's invalid HTML.

```js
$('td.first-row > div input.td-input').on('keydown', makeInput);

function makeInput(event){
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;  // Just need to check which one exists
  if(key == '13'){
    // Doesn't make sense to set up variables for values you'll only use once
    $(this).closest('td').append('<div><input class="td-input"></div>');
    
    // Just de-register the currently registered callback
    $('td.first-row > div input.td-input').off('keydown', makeInput);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-row">
        <div><input class ="td-input"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I got what you are saying, what if I want to add one more div. Using off in this instance would only add one div but if I want the user add as many he wants by pressing enter but each input box should correspond to one key enter event. Sorry, if I'm being unclear with my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<template>` tag

```js
let data = [''];

function setValue(inp, i) {
  data[i] = inp.value;
}

function add(e,i) {
  if (e.key != 'Enter' || i+1<data.length) return;
  data.splice(i+1,0,'');
  show(data);
  cell.children[i+1].children[0].focus();
}

function show(data) {
  let t= item.innerHTML;
  let inj = (s,o)=>s.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g,(x,g)=>o[g]);
  cell.innerHTML=data.map((v,i)=>inj(t,{val:v.replace(/"/g,"&quot;"),i})).join('')
}


show(data);
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-row" id="cell"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<template id="item">
  <div>
    <input 
      class="td-input" 
      onkeypress="add(event,${i})" 
      oninput="setValue(this,${i})" 
      value="${val}" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can we restrict adding the new input when the user presses enter on the same input twice or more?

Comment: Your approach is very interesting, glad I have learned few things from your code but unfortunately ES6 is not compatible in my environment. Thank you though.